# Validating a cell value using XLRD

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am trying to use the package XLRD to read the value of row 2(row 1 in excel), in particular column A.

I know that the value is "text:u'NULL'" but if I try to write an if function which compares a variable which I have given the same value, it does not recognise them as the same.

(Just to explain my spreadsheet has the value *Null* in the cell I am referring to but using XLRD it reads this as "text:u'NULL'" which is fine)

I have created a test example of what I am referring to as this is hard to describe. The value for b on line 20 of my code is definitely "text:u'NULL'", so I have no idea why it does not read this as equal to b.

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("excelscores.xls")
sheet_name = book.sheet_names()[0]
sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
row_no = 1
row = sheet.row(row_no)

## successful test
a = ['lewis','dylan']
b = a[0]
c = 'lewis'
if c == b:
    print "c is equal to b"
else:
    print "fail"

## test that fails
a = row
b = a[0]
c = "text:u'NULL'"
if c == b:
    print "c is equal to b"
else:
    print "fail"enter code here
```

Comment: what is the output when you try print sheet(row_no, 0).value

Comment: I get TypeError: 'Sheet' object is not callable

Comment: I have had another person recommend to me that should maybe update to a newer version of Python (currently on 2.7). Not really sure though? Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey! did the answer work for your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above two values are not equal because **they are of different types**.

Let's say I have this table:

```
| Name | Age |   
| John | 22  |  
| Phil | 25  |
```

Now I want to read the cell (2,1).
 `>>> cell1 = sheet.cell(1,0)`
 `>>> print cell1`
 `text:u'John'`

`>>> match_string = "text:u'John'"`

Now `match_string` and `cell1` appear same. Let's check if they are equal.

`>>> cell1 == match_string`
 `False`

They are not equal. Let's check if they are of the same type:

`>>> isinstance(cell1, basestring)`
 `False`
 `>>> type(cell1)`
 `<class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>`

They are of different types so we just can't compare them.

**Solution:** We can **compare using the value attribute of a cell**.

`>>> cell1_value = cell1.value`
 `>>> print cell1_value`
 `u'John'`

This is of the type  string which now can be used to compare with string type.

`>>> cell1_value==u'John'`
 `True`

So in your case, you can do:
 `>>> row[0].value == u'Null'`
 `True`

This method can also be used to compare for numbers or to check for any condition.